# evenodd fill on a group of shapes

Tags: svg

How would I get an evenodd fill on #g3:

```
<defs>
      <ellipse id="g1" cx="100" cy="100" rx="75" ry="40" fill="none" />
</defs>

<g id="g3" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
  <g id="g2">
    <use xlink:href="#g1" />
    <use xlink:href="#g1" transform="rotate(30 100 100)"/>
  </g>
  <use xlink:href="#g2" transform="rotate(60 100 100)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#g2" transform="rotate(120 100 100)"/>
</g>
```

So iow, its just a series of rotated ellipses, but I want the intersecting regions evenodd filled:

[image] [image]

Just adding fill-rule = "evenodd" to  #g3 doesn't do it.  Sorry if this is too elementary.  I realize there's probably a way to do this in .js, but want to know if it can be done with straight svg.

---

For example, is there a way in which #g3 itself is defined as a new path in some sense, so that evenodd could be applied to it in totality.

Answer (score 0):

I guess just basically draw a series of arcs in one path in a loop from .js - that way its all one path and evenodd fill-type should work, I guess.  Nevermind.